# Two versions of same app

Tags: ios, app-store

Can I push two version of the same app to the store, one more kid friendly the other 17+ if I use two different icons and name the app two slightly different names?

Answer (score 0):

All it matters is that the names are different - Like Angry Birds and Angry Birds Lite. ( speaking from a non-technical point of view, since the question is not technical)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Not speaking from experience.

Besides that, I'm sure you can. App developers offer a free or lite version of an app all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can push two different version of the same app to the App Store. Other than changing the name, the bundle/app ID will/should be different.